# Find parameter of quadratic equation such that it is positive/negative on a range

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification, quadratics

> Find $m\in\mathbb{R}$ such that inequality $x^2-(m+2)x+5-m<0$ is valid $\forall~x\in(1;3)$.

How I think of it:

Set $x^2-(m+2)x+5-m=0$

The parabola will be oriented upwards. In order to satisfy the hypothesis we need the following conditions:

$x_1\leq1,~x_2\geq3$

Write coefficients:

$
\begin{cases}
a=1 \\
b=-(m+2) \\
c=5-m
\end{cases}
$

Calculate discriminant:

$\Delta=b^2-4ac=m^2+8m-16$

Put the condition $\Delta>0$ so the equation will have 2 distinct real roots:

$m^2+8m-16>0$

Set $m^2+8m-16=0$ and find the roots:

$m_1=-4(\sqrt{2}+1),~m_2=4(\sqrt{2}-1)$

$m\in(-\infty;m_1)\cup(m_2;\infty)\Rightarrow m\in\big(-\infty;-4(\sqrt{2}+1)\big)\cup\big(4(\sqrt{2}-1);\infty\big)$

Now find the roots of the initial equation:

$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}=\frac{m+2\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}$

Substitute in the conditions:

$\frac{m+2-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\leq1\Rightarrow m\leq\sqrt{\Delta}$

$\frac{m+2+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\geq3\Rightarrow -m+4\leq\sqrt{\Delta}$

Substitute $\Delta$ and solve the system of inequalities:

$
\begin{cases}
m\leq\sqrt{m^2+8m-16} \\
-m+4\leq\sqrt{m^2+8m-16}
\end{cases}
$

We can square both sides **unless the left hand side is negative**. Example : $-2<1$ but $(-2)^2<1^2$ is false. How can I proceed? One idea would be to make a table of signs for $m$ and $-m+4$ and take in consideration all the possible cases, then take the reunion at the end. Is there an easier way to solve these equations with square roots? Also, am I overcomplicating this problem? Thanks for the help

Comment: Note a minor difference here vs. in the answer posted: you have $x_1\lt 1, x_2\gt 3$ but the conditions you specify allow for $x_1\le 1, x_2\ge 3$.

Comment: @abiessu Got it thanks for noticing the mistake.

Answer (score 5):

You have $(\forall x\in(1,3)):f(x)<0$ if and only if $f(1),f(3)\leqslant0$. Since $f(1)=4-2m$ and $f(3)=8-4m$, you have $f(1),f(3)\leqslant0$ if and only if $4-2m\leqslant0$, which is equivalent to $m\geqslant2$.

Comment: Thanks for sparing me a ton amount of useless work.

Comment: A similar exercise : $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},~f(x)=(a+3)x^2-(a+4)x+a+4, a\in\mathbb{R}-\{3\},~f(x)>0~\forall~x\in(-\infty;0)$. The conditions I would put: 
1. Dominant coefficient positive $\Rightarrow a+3>0$ 
2. $\Delta<0$ (so the function will be positive on $\mathbb{R}$) or : $f(0)>0$ and $x_{min}>0$ 
Is this OK?

I would appreciate if you could also help me on this one because I'm getting confused by these exercises thanks in advance!

Comment: That's another question. I suggest that you post it as such.

Comment: Done : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4195905/condition-that-a-quadratic-equation-is-positive-negative-on-infinite-range